# Best way to process .csv data using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

So everyday i upload (automatically) a lot of .csv files into my s3 bucket and my next step is to join/merge/concat/etc this tables into a more final state in order to upload it to redshift.
In order to do this which service do you recomend me? I have analysed different ways:

s3 -> EC2 -> process data with Python -> Redshift (i don't think this is really efficient)
s3 -> Pipeline -> EMR -> Pipeline -> Redshift (i have 0 knowledge about EMR)
Can i process it ones is already in redshift? Is there any other way? Usually i produce 14M lines of data so it needs to be kind of efficient.

---

The manipulation of the data is just merge or join tables. Example:

Table 1: key, d1, d2, d3

Table 2: key, d4, d5

Expected table on redshift: key, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5

And in another cases just putting one under the other.

Comment: Do you manipulate the contents in any way, or do you just merge multiple files into a single file? Amazon Redshift can load data from multiple files -- in fact, this is the recommended method because it can parallelize the process. Feel free to Edit your question to add additional detail about what your process is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift can easily handle this and is likely to be 100x faster than your mentioned methods.

Use `COPY` to load the CSVs into separate staging and then insert them into a final table (and truncate the staging tables if needed).

```
INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT a.key, a.d1, a.d2, a.d3, b.d4, b.d5
FROM table_1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS b
USING (key);
```

Comment: While this is actually true you are really limited when it comes to process data using staging tables. Just in case anyone else is wondering the correct way to go is using EMR and a script. I would recommend using Spark since it integrates with Python through pyspark.

Comment: How are staging tables "really limited"? Why is EMR the "correct way"? The OP has data in 2 CSVs and wants to join them and persist as a table. The OP already has a Redshift cluster so the answer given seems to me to be the simplest (and fastest) approach.

Comment: Well since im the OP and clearly i wasn't explaining ALL the aspects of the situation.... :D thanks anyway it was really helpfull.